# How can I use Arial Narrow in the VSCode editor?

Tags: fonts, vscode, arial

I use `VSCode` along with `MiKTeX`. Although `XeLaTeX` and `LuLaTeX` seem to be installed when I checked on `MiKTeX`, I cannot use the `\fontspec` package to use Arial Narrow.

Comment: Have you tried something? Show a MWE code?

Comment: You've got to give us something to work with, like an example. Your choice of editor has almost certainly nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

(Adding as an answer, because unlike comments it allows me to properly format my code)

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% With LuaLaTeX, specifying the font by name uses the Italic variant, for some reason:
%\setmainfont{Arial Narrow} 

% If using XeLaTeX is not an option, we need to specify the font by file name:
\setmainfont{ARIALN.TTF}    

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

This works for me on TeXLive 2022 / Windows 10.